# Change preserveaspectratio attribute of SVG inside Lottie player

Tags: javascript, html, lottie

I have embeded a lottie json file using lottie player. I do not have access to SVG file. I only have json file. I want to change `preserveaspectratio` attribute of SVG to `xMinYMax meet` instead of `xMinYMin meet`. I tried different things but none of them worked so far. Forexample, I tried to set `preserveaspectratio` attribute on lottie player tag. I also tried to select svg using js but does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@0.4.0/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
<style>
    body{
        padding: 0; margin: 0;
    }
    div{
        max-width: 1000px;
        margin: auto;
        width: 100%; background: red;
        height: 700px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <lottie-player autoplay loop mode="normal" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet" style="width: 100%;">
        </lottie-player>
    </div>

     
    <script>
        
        
        const player = document.querySelector("lottie-player");
        player.load("./graduation-hd.json");
        console.log(player);
        // player.preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet";
        // console.log(player)

        player.addEventListener('ready', function(){
            console.log('ready');
            var $svg = document.querySelector('lottie-player svg');
            $svg.setAttribute('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMax meet');
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access to the SVG element using this syntax:
`document.querySelector('lottie-player svg')`, because the `document` doesn't know the SVG element is a child of the `<lottie-player/>` component.

Here is the solution:

```js
const player = document.querySelector("lottie-player");
const svg = player.shadowRoot.querySelector("svg")
svg.setAttribute('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMax meet');
```

**Why?** That's because Lottie creates a [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) (for perf and encapsulation reasons).

`<lottie-player/>` acts as a *Shadow host* (The regular DOM node that the shadow DOM is attached to).

Thus a *Shadow root* is attached to it. Consider the *Shadow root* as an equivalent of `document`. It contains a tree as well, has similar methods as the `document` like `querySelector`. The key point is that the *Shadow root* tree is not visible from the `document` context.

The tree inside the *Shadow root* is called *Shadow tree*, which contains the SVG element that you need to select.